# Is it ethical for a student to earn a PhD by working as a team leader?

Tags: phd, ethics

I know several doctoral students in the field of deep learning. Their main job is to be the technical leader (full-time job, even not taking doctoral courses) in the company. They only propose research topics and write papers, and all experiments are completed by other engineers. These doctoral students will be the first authors of the papers and ultimately earn a degree based on these papers, is this behavior ethical?

---

I think I should describe it more clearly. These doctoral students mainly play the role of managers, who have **strong management skills** but **limited  theoretical knowledge** of related disciplines. For example, when they see that the diffusion model is very popular recently, they will ask engineers to investigate the diffusion model and explain it to them, and then they will arrange engineers to test the effect of the diffusion model on related interdisciplinary tasks. If the engineers encounter difficulties, they will arrange for other people with the knowledge and ability to assist as need.

Comment: Who will give them a PhD? And why would it not be ethical for someone to receive a PhD if a university wants to give them one and they’ve fulfilled the requirements?

Comment: This is because the experiments in the papers are conducted by others. They themselves are only familiar with the basic concepts but not the details.

Comment: Could you expatiate on ... *all experiments are conducted by other engineers*" ...

Comment: If a researcher or *doctoral student* were to be in humanities and all statistical analysis were done by others, say statisticians, would the researcher or doctoral student be ethical or unethical to lay claim to the research and research outcome?

Comment: @semmyk-research The codes and experiments are written and conducted by the engineers in the company. If positive results are obtained, these doctoral students (majoring in computer science) will write the papers.

Comment: It sounds as if you already decided the answer to your question, as you reveal more and more of the situation. You should ask what to do about it, then.

Comment: Is this in a German speaking country?

Answer (score 4):

The contribution of a Ph.D. thesis needs to be attributable to the person and fulfill requirements such as significance and originality. It can depend on the work of others, even to the extent that this work is indispensable.

Proposing research topics sounds a bit weak, but we do not know the details of their importance. In my opinion, a proposal that lays procedure out such that the mythical average capable engineer of patent law following the established procedures of their field can perform the research and obtain the results is an independent, attributable contribution that derives its significance from the significance of the complete research. There is no requirement that a researcher has to do everything in the research.

Indeed, such a requirement would quickly lead to abstruse situations. If I were to use (not yet, but almost existing) AI to write simple Python scripts, the result is mine. If I ask someone to write the Python scripts for me, do the results stop being mine? Or, if I were to write the Python scripts myself, do I need to attribute the results equally to the implementers and designers of NumPy and similar modules? Similarly, would research in epidemiology only be valid for a Ph.D. if all the testing and the sample analysis involved would be done by the person aspiring to the doctorate? With other words, some collaboration and some reliance on the work by others is to be expected.

I am not sure about your experience with research, but from my experience I can assure you that some of the most difficult challenges in research is finding good research topics. Ordering a competent engineer to perform an experiment does not invalidate the contribution of the one ordering it.

Ultimately, the ethics of the situation depends on the details of the situation, most importantly the novelty and significance of the topics proposed as well as how easy it would be for someone in the field to perform these tasks.  It could well be that there is little significance in what the Ph.D. candidates are contributing, but it could also be a lot. The decision first rests with the Ph.D. committee at their universities, who presumably can read between the lines in order to assess the individual contributions. If you think yourself competent to judge that there is no significant contribution and that inferiors are asked to do the research for the superior, then you could (anonymously) inform the chair of the department, who could then raise the issue with the committee members if they deem your concern credible.

Comment: "the ethics of the situation depends on the details of the situation" - in particular, on whether the team leader tells the truth with clarity in their thesis about who contributed what.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned

> *They {<s>only</s>} propose research topics and write papers, and all experiments are completed by other engineers*

Depending on what *all experiments are completed by other engineers* is, the ***research*** is *completed* by them (the doctoral student).
The *engineers* can be seen in the same light as *technicians/programmers* working in (university) lab.

At times, doctoral students and postdocs get *stuck* in the coding, because of the *search* for novelty, and neglect the *research*. There should be balance.

Comment: I think I should describe it more clearly. These doctoral students study interdisciplinary subjects (deep learning & chemistry), and they don’t have much theoretical knowledge, but they are very familiar with popular topics in deep learning and cheminformatics. For example, when they notice that the diffusion model is very popular recently, they will ask an engineer to investigate the diffusion model and report to him, and then they will arrange for the engineer to test the effect of the diffusion model on tasks in cheminformatics.

Answer (score 0):

If a PhD student does work that a university believes merits awarding them a PhD, then the student is acting ethically. The university is the one that decides what the standard is for receiving a PhD carrying its name. If they set the standard too low and award PhD degrees for too little work, or for work that doesn’t develop appropriate research skills, the university will quickly develop a reputation as little more than a diploma mill and its degrees will be seen as worthless.

The above analysis is assuming that the student is not misleading the university about the scope of the work they are doing. If the student pretends to be doing work that others are doing, obviously that is unethical behavior and constitutes serious misconduct.